# Nesting CSS inside CSS

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I am making a simple social network, and I'm putting placeholders in the text boxes. I am styling the placeholders so they have a color, but that color is the same color the text boxes  are when you hover. You wouldn't see the placeholders anymore. The method of styling I'm using is:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #73318e;
}
```

I want to put this inside the

```
#type:hover, #input:hover {

}
```

to make it so when you hover, the placeholders color changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this what you are looking for:

```
#input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
    color: #73318e;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQ7Aw/)**

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I tried doing this with javascript/jquery, but I realized that the placeholders didn't have an id/class, so I couldn't get to them using js

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work in Chrome:

```
input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/94LaL/

You could've guessed that. Haven't tested in any other browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#myInput::-webkit-input-placeholder
{ color: #73318e; }
#myInput:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder
{ color: transparent; }

#myInput:-moz-placeholder
{
    opacity: 1; /* Removes default transparency */
    color: #73318e;
}
#myInput:hover:-moz-placeholder
{ color: transparent; }

#myInput::-moz-placeholder
{
    opacity: 1; /* Removes default transparency */
    color: #73318e;
}
#myInput:hover::-moz-placeholder
{ color: transparent; }

#myInput:-ms-input-placeholder
{ color: #73318e; }
#myInput:hover
:-ms-input-placeholder
{ color: transparent; }
```

Working example:
[codepen.io/anon/pen/BAwEF](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BAwEF)